# AngularJS $http.get() inside a local function that returns bool

Tags: angularjs, http

I'm new to AngularJS.

I have this local function inside of one of my angularjs controllers that I call when I do some action. Thank you in advance!

```
$scope.AddUser = () => {

   if(validateUser()) {
      doSomething();
   }
}

function validateUser() {

     //-- This one works
     if(....) {
       return false;
     }

     //-- Even after returning false, it still reaches 
     //-- the last line which is return true therefore executing the 
     //-- doSomething() function
     $http({
       ....
       ....
       }).then(function success(response){
          if(response.data) {
            return false;
          }
       },function error(response) {
          return false;
     });

  return true;
}
```

Comment: Edit. I also tried removing the last line, and putting it in the else statement. See below:


`$http({
       ....
       ....
       }).then(function success(response){
          if(response.data) {
            return false;
          }
          else {
            return true;
          }
       },function error(response) {
          return false;
     });`

This time, the doSomething() function is not firing...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$http` call is asynchronous, so function reaches this line before you get the result of http get:

```
return true;
```

You need to modify `validateUser` to return a promise:

```
function validateUser() {


     return $http({
       ....
       ....
       }).then(function success(response){
          if(response.data) {
            return false;
          }
       },function error(response) {
          return false;
     });


}
```

and use it like this:

```
validateUser().then((result)=> {
    if (result) doSomething();
})
```

Comment: Hi @Bill-P, thank you so much for your help. I was able to make it work, but I needed to create a separate function for the $http.get({}) alone. Nevertheless its not a problem. Cheers!